# Dúvida ~iniciante sobre 2 android SDK`s no mesmo pc

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio, instalador, android-sdk

Fiz o download do Visual Studio e junto com ele também instalei o android sdk,mas a IDE Android Studio vem junto com o sdk;já procurei as pastas do Android SDK mas existem muitas com o mesmo nome,como instalar o Android Studio sem gerar problemas?

P.S:Peço desculpas se essa foi uma pergunta idiota

Notebook Acer Aspire E 15,Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Pode instalar o Android Studio sem qualquer problema.
Haver dois Android SDk não traz problemas no funcionamento do Visual Studio ou no Android Studio.

No entanto é preferível que ambos trabalhem com o mesmo. Isso evitará, para manter o SDK actualizado, ter de descarregar duas vezes a mesma actualização.

Tanto o Visual Studio como o Android Studio têm a opção de indicar a localização do Android SDK a usar.

- **Visual Studio 2017**
  Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager
  Android SDK Location

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Android Studio 3.0.1**
  Tools > Android > SDK Manager
  Appearance & Behavior > Android SDK
  Android SDK Location

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nota: A forma de chegar a **Android SDK Location** pode variar em função da versão da IDE

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta,infelizmente não posso ''dar upvote'' no seu comentário mas agradeço

Comment: Por que diz que não pode? O facto de ter menos de 15 pontos de reputação não o inibe de votar e/ou aceitar respostas a perguntas suas.